# CKAN uses jsonpdataproxy.appspot.com instead of local dataset

Tags: ckan

I am migrating from CKAN 2.3 to CKAN 2.5.2. The migration was succesfull but the data grid is not showing data because it is going to jsonpdataproxy.appspot.com instead of querying directly to dataset.

The dataset is enabled and works properly. I test it using `curl -I -k -X GET "https://127.0.0.1:444/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=_table_metadata"`

If I return to CKAN 2.3, only changing the code and Solr schema not config file or other configuration, the data grid is shown again. Any advice to solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: With that upgrade path I can imagine you are suffering from the datastore_active field not being set correctly (e.g. https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/2234) but you seem to have found a fix for that. Did you perform a DB upgrade as part of your upgrade?

Comment: Yes the problem was that `datastore_active` field always came with false value. I perform a DB upgrade also.

Answer (score 1):

Finally the problem was solved.

I see the problem was in the var `datastore_active` came with `false` value and this make that Ckan use jsonpdataproxy.appspot.com.

Looking in code where this variable is changed finally I found that this variable is stablished in the `resource` table in `extras` column as a json. I updated all the resources (`update resource set extras ='{"datastore_active": true}';`) and regenerate the Solr Index and the data grid is shown again.

I execute the command:

`paster --plugin=ckan views create --yes --config=/etc/ckan/${BASE_NAME}/production.ini --no-default-filters`

But it returns next error:

`/usr/local/ckan/venv_test/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/default_comparator.py:33: SAWarning: The IN-predicate on "group.name" was invoked with an empty sequence. This results in a contradiction, which nonetheless can be expensive to evaluate.  Consider alternative strategies for improved performance.
  return o[0](self, self.expr, op, *(other + o[1:]), **kwargs)
2016-10-03 13:40:56,802 INFO  [ckan.lib.cli] Done`

I don't know if this error makes that the datagrid wasn't shown in the migration.

Comment: I am not sure if this command works or not because I did it in a previous migration to CKAN 2.3 and the views appear correctly, so may be the views were created correctly before. However the command returns a zero _return code_ and an ok message  `2016-10-03 13:40:56,802 INFO  [ckan.lib.cli] Done`